# How should I conceal helper classes from the rest of the world?

Tags: c++, namespaces, encapsulation, nested-class

I have a few classes. One class is supposed to be visible to anybody that needs it, and the rest are helper classes (well, some of them are structs) that should only be accessible to the principal class. I originally had this implemented as a nested class inside the principal class, but that was starting to make the header file cumbersome as I added more helper classes. So now I've put the helper classes in a separate namespace with a forbidding kind of name, but I suspect there's a better way. I'd like to use an anonymous namespace, but I can't really take the helper classes out of the header, because they appear as member variables in the principal class.

Here's a simplified version of the construction that's in my header file now, minus include guards:

```
namespace __TopSecretVisibleNamespace {
    class Invisible{
    };
}

using namespace __TopSecretVisibleNamespace;
class Visible {
    public:
        Visible();
    private:
        Invisible sneaky;
};
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: The usual convention is a `detail` namespace. `__T...` is reserved for the implementation (as is any name with a double underscore *or* a leading underscore followed by a capital letter).

Comment: Yup, `detail`. And don't do `using namespace detail`, it kind of defeats the point.

Comment: Jerry-What do you mean by "reserved for the implementation?" I can't implement classes in a different namespace than I declare them in, can I?
Cat - Ooh, thanks, I thought the using statement didn't carry outside the header file.

Comment: Reserved means you're not allowed to use identifiers like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can't literally 'conceal' them, but you can make them inaccessible by any other class by using `protected` modifier. If, for any reason, you don't want to use protected on all the class members, you can use it only on the construtor. In that case, non-friend classes cannot access any member of the class, including the public ones.

```
 class Invisible {
    friend class Visible;
    protected:
    Invisible() {
    }
    public:
    // though public, they cannot be called by classes other than Visible, because they can't instantiate the class.
    int Calc(int n)  
    {
        return n*n;
    }
    int i;  
};

class Visible {
    public:
    Visible(int i)
    {
        Invisible o;
        x=o.Calc(i);
    }
    int x;
};
```